# Auto-launching apps URI associations for Windows Phone 8 ' shows Sorry no apps found'

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have published an Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight application in to the store. And I integrated [Auto-launching apps URI associations for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Howassociationworksfortheuser) with this build.

So that my application can be open from any other application by just calling the uri schema.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("mypp:"));
```

And it open my app from another application if it already installed on the device.

In case the user did not install my app, it shows **Search for app in the store** message dialog, and clicking on this store app get opens, searching for application and shows **'Sorry, no apps found'**

What I missed to implement here? I need to show my app in the list when the they search in the store.

I checked with 'foursquare:' & 'metrotube' , It shows in the search list if it is not previously installed.
Please suggest what I missed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately `LauncherOptions` is not supported for Windows Phone 8. Any alternative for this ?**

My issue has been resolved by adding Launch options with the Launch Uri method.But it is supported in windows phone 8.1 version.

```
 private async void LaunchChillr(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
      options.FallbackUri = new Uri("http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=0dff7a2f-51f8-xxxx-8ff7-5e9ddab540c0");
      options.TreatAsUntrusted = true;
      await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("myapp:"), options);
   }
```